# Knockout isDirty example, using dynamic viewmodule from mapping plugin

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm using [Ryan Niemeyer's Dirty Flag](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html).
An example of his method can be seen in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/dtpfv/).

He has a dirtyItems method on the ViewModel

```
this.dirtyItems = ko.computed(function() {
  return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.items(), function(item) {
    return item.dirtyFlag.isDirty();
  });
}, this);
```

However, I can't seem to get his dirtyItems method working with my data.The biggest difference is that I am using the mapping plugin. 
Everything I have tried comes back empty.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UcyDv/1/) of my implementation.

Comment: What level do you want your flag to be at? Do you want it to be per Category or per Profile Property?

Comment: Maybe I wrongly assumed it was set on any observable (like ProfilePropertyValue), and any change would propagate it up so that every parent level would also show as dirty. 
If it has to be one or the other, then i want it to be set at the ProfilePropertyValue level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add the dirtyFlag to the ProfilePropertyValue like:

```
var mappingOptions = {
    ProfilePropertyValue: {
        create: function (mappingoptions) {
            var data = mappingoptions.data;
            data.ProfilePropertyValue = data.ProfilePropertyValue || {
                "ID": null,
                    "Checkbox": ko.observable(false)
            };

            var result = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
            result.dirtyFlag = ko.dirtyFlag(result);

            return result;
        }
    }
};
```

Then, you would need to check it when building your list of dirty items, if that is something that you need.

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/7DGfs/

Comment: This looks great, a large part of my problem solved. 
Now, how would I return just **ProfilePropertyValue**'s from _viewModel.dirtyItems_ that are dirty instead of the entire Category containing Properties and ProfilePropertyValue?

Comment: You can change the filter function to be more like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/W3zkQ/

Comment: Thanks, I considered using foreach, but thought it was possible using arrayFilter.