# I need a global event when data binding occurs in Knockout

Tags: events, knockout.js

I am a newbie to knockoutjs. I have searched examples and so far no luck. I have a page that is a data collection form with the values bound using knockout. What I am trying to do is provide the user with a flag letting him know data is modified and that it needs to be saved. In the app a user may pull down the form and display the data from the server and use it only as information. In other cases he may modify that data. I want to display a label that says something like "data has been modified" to the user once any binding has changed plus if he tries to navigate away from the page I want to warn him the changes will be lost. Is there some event I can subscribe to that tells me when any value has been changed in the model?

Thanks,
Terry

Comment: I understand your reasoning but what if there are other bindings on the page outside the form? It would also be good to know if value had *really* changed to something else (e.g. not being reverted after a while). Therefore, I would suggest using [observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) and subscribe only to required fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Ryan Niemeyer's Dirty Flag](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html). It might be what you are looking for. An example of his method can be seen in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/dtpfv/).

```
this.dirtyItems = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.items(), function(item) {
        return item.dirtyFlag.isDirty();
    });
}, this);
```

More info can be found in this SO thread: [Knockout isDirty example, using dynamic viewmodule from mapping plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365525/knockout-isdirty-example-using-dynamic-viewmodule-from-mapping-plugin)

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need - thanks. So far I have not been able to get it to work on my site. My view model is coming down from AJAX as a minimal dataset and then I map it to the observables and I am sure I have something wrong there. Thanks again.